# Not enough catalyst data for SMOG inspection even after 350 miles

Tags: acura, emissions, rsx

Place: California
Car: 2003 Acura RSX Type-S

I went on 4 week vacation in Dec, my car sat in garage. Now I have trouble getting my SMOG passed, I am getting catalyst data not ready reading, even after driving over 350 miles. Car runs great, the catalytic converter also seems to work well, I do not smell any CO in my garage.

Comment: How do you smell CO - it is colorless and odorless and tasteless.

Comment: Somewhat sweet smell, tell-tell headache. Just few seconds behind an old pickup truck or near a 2-stroke leaf blower is enough. Many people can smell/detect CO.

Comment: That is not CO - it is other products of combustion.

Comment: No, you can't smell CO regardless of what you think.  Please take the car to a professional mechanic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a specialist in Milpitas, CA, who fixed it. There was an exhaust leak upstream of the catalyst that confused the car sensors/computer. After the leak got fixed, the car started to report catalyst reduced efficiency code and the catalytic converter had to be replaced.

Summary: Replacement of the catalyst and repair of the exhaust leak fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you've recently changed your catalytic converter or replaced/upgraded any of the computer/sensor components, then it likely needs more driving. My buddy (a pro mechanic) always recommends ~500 miles. Idk if this is just his *personal* rules of thumb or based on actual sensor training.

That said, if you haven't changed anything in within the last few months (or <500 miles), then take it in for some thorough diagnosis. If the cat is 17 years old, it may need replacing. Same with many of the computer/sensor components. But I also want to reinforce the note in the comments: the CO itself does *not* have any odor, and you should be sure to handle the issue to avoid any (potentially worse) other outcomes.

Also, if you disconnected your battery, or had a weak or old battery, then your computer could have lost all its data from sitting for 4 weeks. I don't believe it's the same on *all* modern vehicles, but I do know that some cars' computers will forget learned dara, or even become totally corrupted, from sitting too long without power. So this is something that *could* possibly be the case for you... I say "could" because I dont know the your car specifically. Of this is the case, then it would likely need to relearn everything.